# Trying to pass List of Ints as an argument in scala function when calling it

Tags: scala

I've written a function with the following signature

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int =
```

When I try to call it and pass arguments I get a type mismatch error

I tried `countChange(10, [1, 2])` and `countChange(10, List[1, 2])` with no luck

Comment: `[1,2]` is not the syntax for List construction. Lists are not a built in linguistic structure, but just another library. Try `countChange(10, List(1,2))`

Comment: Make it the answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1,2] is not the syntax for List construction. Lists are not a built in linguistic structure, but just another library. Try countChange(10, List(1,2))